# Py2App: Alias mode works, but deployment doesn't

Tags: python, py2app

I'm trying to deploy my python application using py2app.

I created the setup file using : `py2applet --make-setup MyApplication.py`

Then I did this to test it : `python setup.py py2app -A`

That worked as well. My GUI program runs.

When I try the last step: `python setup.py py2app`

I get this fat error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 18, in <module>
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 659, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 865, in _run
    self.run_normal()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 959, in run_normal
    self.create_binaries(py_files, pkgdirs, extensions, loader_files)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1214, in create_binaries
    platfiles = mm.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/macholib/MachOStandalone.py", line 105, in run
    mm.run_file(fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/macholib/MachOGraph.py", line 84, in run_file
    self.scan_node(m)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/macholib/MachOGraph.py", line 110, in scan_node
    m = self.load_file(filename, caller=node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/macholib/MachOGraph.py", line 93, in load_file
    newname = self.locate(name, loader=caller)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/macholib/MachOStandalone.py", line 23, in locate
    newname = super(FilteredMachOGraph, self).locate(filename, loader)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/macholib/MachOGraph.py", line 49, in locate
    loader=loader.filename)
TypeError: dyld_find() got an unexpected keyword argument 'loader'
```

Why is this happening? I've spend the last few hours trying to deploy. No luck with py2app, cx_freeze, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround: edit the file `MachOGraph.py` which in your case is located there:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/macholib/MachOGraph.py
```

Search for the term `loader=loader.filename)` and replace it with `loader_path=loader.filename)`

Credits goes to *David Goldenberg* for its post on bitbucket.org. https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app/issues/137/py2app-problems-using-enthought-python

Answer (score 1):

Pillow was the problem. Py2Applet doesn't play nice with it. Got rid of Pillow, and all is well.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I don't have Pillow installed and I still get this error.